# JSoup - Select all comments

Tags: java, screen-scraping, extract, comments, jsoup

I want to select all comments from a document using JSoup. I would like to do something like this:

```
for(Element e : doc.select("comment")) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

I have tried this:

```
for (Element e : doc.getAllElements()) {
  if (e instanceof Comment) {

  }
```

}

But the following error occurs in eclipse "Incompatible conditional operand types Element and Comment".

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `Comment extends Node` you need to apply `instanceof` to the node objects, not the elements, like this:

```
    for(Element e : doc.getAllElements()){
        for(Node n: e.childNodes()){
            if(n instanceof Comment){
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) you can get via Jsoup every `Comment` of the whole `Document` or a specific `Element` with:

```
fun Element.getAllComments(): List<Comment> {
  return this.allElements.flatMap { element ->
    element.childNodes().filterIsInstance<Comment>()
  }
}
```