# How can I count the Comments and the lines of a webpage using Jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Hello guys I am trying to make an html parser using jsoup.How can I count the comments and the lines of an html document?

Answer (score 1):

As [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063371) you can iterate over every [Node](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html), check if it’s an Instance of [Comment](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Comment.html) and count.

Counting the lines of the HTML can be done by splitting it at every line-break:

```
int lines = doc.html().split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selector syntax api for tags which are related to comments. (It's not the same tag for any websites.) Also, you may find the tags which you need to parse via browser's dev tools. (firebug, chrome dev tool etc.)

[Selector syntax for jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Good luck...