# Partial parse Comment tag in JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to check if HTML comment tags are inserted properly.. If there is the opening tag but no closing tag, i want to display error.

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063263/jsoup-select-all-comments) and was able to retrieve valid comment nodes

```
for(Element e : document.getAllElements()){
            for(Node n: e.childNodes()){
                if(n instanceof Comment){
                    commentNodes++;
                    System.out.println(n);
                }
            }
        }
        if(html.contains("<!--") && commentNodes == 0) {
            System.out.println("error");
        } else  if(html.contains("-->") && commentNodes == 0) {
            System.out.println("error1");
        }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether JSoup will parse not closed comment tag, although there's another way to achieve your goal:

```
int openings = StringUtils.countMatches(html, "<!--");
int closures = StringUtils.countMatches(html, "-->");
if (openings > closures)
    System.out.println("Error: There are not closed comment tags!");
```

It will count number of occurrences of comment tag openings and closures and by comparing it you can assume whether there is an not closed. To be entirely certain the result you can also compare the values with number of tags obtained by JSoup (`commentNodes` in your example).